# Должен ли я проводить доп. проверку после assert?

Tags: c, opengl, шейдеры

Всем привет! Есть код на Си инициализации шейдеров (OpenGL). Заголовок файла:

```
struct Shader {
    GLuint vertex;
    GLuint fragment;
    GLuint program;
}

GLuint initShaders();

bool isStateError();

void cleanShaders();
```

Исходный код:

```
#include "../Includes/Shader.h"

// TODO: Load shaders from files

const GLchar *VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n\0";

const GLchar *FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";

const Shader shader;

GLuint initShaders() {
    GLint isSuccess;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    GLenum error;

    shader.vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    assert(shader.vertex == GL_INVALID_ENUM || shader.vertex == 0);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    glShaderSource(shader.vertex, 1, &VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE, NULL);

    error = glGetError();

    assert(error != GL_NO_ERROR);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    glCompileShader(shader.vertex);

    error = glGetError();

    assert(error != GL_NO_ERROR);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    glGetShaderiv(shader.vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isSuccess);

    error = glGetError();

    assert(error != GL_NO_ERROR);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    if (!isSuccess) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader.vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);

        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", infoLog);

        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    shader.fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    assert(shader.fragment == GL_INVALID_ENUM || shader.fragment == 0);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    glShaderSource(shader.fragment, 1, &FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE, NULL);

    error = glGetError();

    assert(error != GL_NO_ERROR);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    glCompileShader(shader.fragment);

    error = glGetError();

    assert(error != GL_NO_ERROR);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    glGetShaderiv(shader.fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isSuccess);

    error = glGetError();

    assert(error != GL_NO_ERROR);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    if (!isSuccess) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader.fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog);

        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", infoLog);

        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    shader.program = glCreateProgram();

    assert(shader.program == 0);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    glAttachShader(shader.program, shader.vertex);

    error = glGetError();

    assert(error != GL_NO_ERROR);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    glAttachShader(shader.program, shader.fragment);

    error = glGetError();

    assert(error != GL_NO_ERROR);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    glLinkProgram(shader.program);

    error = glGetError();

    assert(error != GL_NO_ERROR);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    glGetProgramiv(shader.program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &isSuccess);

    error = glGetError();

    assert(error != GL_NO_ERROR);

    // Check for in release build
    if (isStateError()) {
        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    if (!isSuccess) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader.program, 512, NULL, infoLog);

        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", infoLog);

        cleanShaders();

        return NULL;
    }

    return shader.program;
}

bool isStateError() {
    if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void cleanShaders() {
    assert(shader == NULL);
    assert(shader.vertex == NULL);
    assert(shader.fragment == NULL);
    assert(shader.program == NULL);

    // Check for in release build
    if (shader != NULL) {
        if (shader.vertex != NULL) {
            glDeleteShader(shader.vertex);
        }

        if (shader.fragment != NULL) {
            glDeleteShader(shader.fragment);
        }

        if (shader.program != NULL) {
            glDeleteProgram(shader.program);
        }

        shader = NULL;
    }
}
```

Как видите это просто инициализаця шейдера. К моменту рендеринга я должен быть уверен что все настроено правильно и готово к рендеру. Поэтому считаю что такие проверки в момент инициализации уместны. Но в релизе обычно ассерты не включаются а состояние может быть некорректным. И поэтому надо оставлять такие проверки после ассерта?

```
// Check for in release build
if (isStateError()) {
    cleanShaders();

    return NULL;
}
```

И вообще каков best practise на этот счет? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: ассерты используются для проверки логики.

Comment: Ассерты используются для ловли ситуаций, которые считаются вообще невозможными, так что вы неправильно используете их здесь

Comment: Спасибо! Нашел примеры от Khronos Group. Эти ребята вообще не парятся. Делают несколько основных проверок и в продакшн. Ссылка: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Example_Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, мое ИМХО (имею мнение - хрен оспоришь :)) - что `assert` - средство сугубо отладочное. Ваше

```
assert(shader.vertex == GL_INVALID_ENUM || shader.vertex == 0);
```

означает, что при *нормальной* работе приложения неприятности гарантированно не возникнут. Вы просто хотите убедиться в этом во время отладки - что таких ситуация не будет в принципе.

Если же при обычной работе такая ситуация возможна - для каких-то данных - и вы как-то обрабатываете эту ситуацию - то здесь как раз совершенно лишний `assert`, потому что вы должны отладить и такие ситуации, а не просто завершить программу.

Так что мое мнение - или-или. Можно и одновременно, но смысла не вижу...

Comment: assert(shader.vertex != GL_INVALID_ENUM && shader.vertex != 0); Когда true выполняемся дальше иначе падаем. Но не суть)